# Object appears to be overlapping in object view

Tags: error

[image]When panning around in the view port and rendered mode artefacts show randomly, I have checked if any duplicate vertices, and gone in the wire frame mode and everything appears normal,I have also pulled around the vertices and faces to see if any overlap and have also set a material to the object but the problem still persists. I am a relatively new to Blender and its likely to be an easy fix, Any ideas at what could be happening here? Thank you

Update: Even when adding a new object straight away it had this problem, so has likely nothing to do with any editing to the mesh and might be a problem with blender it's self.

[Blend File](https://drive.google.com/open?id=15kqguOg0k-t1TwMnKcYdOnK3QOdx_B6e)
Version is 2.82
Render engine Eevee

Comment: pls share file, thanks

Comment: While sharing the file helps, it's a good idea to mention what version of Blender you use and if you post screenshots, please do not remove the little clues there are by cutting it down to the issue, but leave the screenshot show the interface setup. We can only play detective based on experience and for that we need clues. So showing more pictures of settings, possible modifiers used and display mode (Eevee, Cycles, Material Preview, Solid) can all help. Regarding sharing the file [Blender-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) can be used.